# Search a file for lines NOT containing a phrase with context

Tags: grep

I have a file with many entries consisting of a keyword followed by several lines of numbers.  I want to filter out one category of entries, so if entry derp is followed by three lines I want something like `grep -v -A3 derp filename` to get every entry in filename that is NOT of type derp.  The problem is `-v` and `-A` appear to be incompatible.  When both flags are used, `-v` is ignored.  How else can I do this?
The file looks like this:

`SOURCE: pI < min           45           16            0 
7.4871483836177132E-004   5.1628324610858206E-004   -1.826383220714803      -9.4293105782888549E-004  -6.8875048798939895E-002  -0.2196057448134437      -6.6270591049115615E-003
SOURCE: pI < min           45           17            0 
7.1266687952112871E-004   5.1628324610858206E-004   -2.169039713847648      -1.1198388644036935E-003  -8.2240618017566103E-002  -9.0412967200093102E-005 
-7.5453919169102962E-003
SOURCE: pI < min           45           18            0 
7.0936181176839061E-004   5.1628324610858206E-004   -2.589392543137075      -1.3368599876201657E-003  -9.8187643312659903E-002  -1.1762198384731523E-005 
-9.4417591779528513E-003`

This continues in similar fashion for many thousand lines.  Occasionally there is an entry beginning with something other than `SOURCE: pI < min`.  It is these entries I want to find.  The file is ~50Mb.

Comment: What about `grep -v "$(grep -A3 derp filename)" filename`? If you know number of context below each derp.

Comment: @mohammad.k the inner `grep -A3` in `grep -v "$(grep -A3 derp filename)" filename` has several hundred thousand results, so the outer `grep -v` just says "argument list too long."

Comment: @don_crissti  If I knew what (if any) other entries were contained in the file,  my question would be unnecessary because I could simply grep for them.  That is not the case here.  The question clearly states the desired output: everything EXCEPT the example text.

Comment: @MatthewBedford - all right, I think I get it... each `SOURCE: pI < min...` line is followed by another three lines so you have blocks of 4 lines (where the first matches that pattern) that you want to remove from the file... Is that right ?

Comment: That is correct.  The method of @mohammad.k would give exactly what I need if it were not for the length of the inner grep output.

Comment: @MatthewBedford - not necessarily, unless you can guarantee that none of the context lines for `no_match` has a duplicate among the context lines for `match`.

Answer (score 3):

I found something that works:

```
grep -A3 derp filename | diff - filename
```

Answer (score 1):

What about doing this from a different direction ?

```
sed '/pattern/,+3d' input_file
```

Alternatively, if you don't have `gnu sed`:

```
sed '/pattern/ {N;N;N;d;} input_file
```

Will display all text, minus any line containing the pattern, and the 3 lines that follow that line.

or if you want to edit the file in-place:

```
sed -i '/pattern/,+3d' input_file
```

if `-i` is not supported by your `sed`:

```
sed '/pattern/ {N;N;N;d;} inputfile > output_file
mv output_file input_file
```

These should essentially do what you want... i.e. with a file that contains

```
cat
dog
dog
dog
horse
```

I would get only `horse` as a result, if `cat` was my pattern.

Comment: hmmm so... `sed 'N;N;N; /pattern/d' <file>`?

Comment: It seemed to work without the  {}, but I'm not sure of the limited use case, or something with GNU sed...so With it... `sed -e '/pattern/ {N;N;N;d;} <file>` also seems to work...

Comment: Dang, thanks for the prodding. you literally just opened a completely new door of understanding of sed for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Aassuming that the unwanted other entries were all non-numeric, you could contruct a list of them with `grep -v '^([0-9-]+|SOURCE:)' filename`.  This outputs the entire matching lines so would need futher processing.

If they all follow the pattern of a word followed by a colon, you could use `awk -F: '!/^([0-9]+|SOURCE:)/ { print $1}'`.

Once you have the list, you can use it to build a regular expression matching them all, and then use that in `sed` to delete 4 lines every time it found one of the matches.

For example:

```
LIST=$(awk -F: '!/^([0-9-]+|SOURCE:)/ { print $1}' filename | sort -u)
RE=$(echo $LIST | sed -e 's/ /|/g')

sed -r -e "s/^($RE):/,4 d" filename
```

If you need to perform further processing on the list before building the regular expression, e.g. to remove some entries, you could do it like this:

```
RE=$(echo "$LIST" | egrep -v '^(FOO|BAR)$' | xargs echo | sed -e 's/ /|/g')
```

Note the double-quotes around "$LIST" this time - this preserves line breaks for egrep to use (which is why we have to pipe it through `xargs echo` later to get all the list entries on one line for `sed`).